# sql-server: creating 3 date ranges with DATEADD()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create 3 date ranges from `Time_Stamp` where `MainHospital='Hospital1'`. Hospital1 returns these results in column Time_Stamp from table `Survey`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhYDI.png

Each date range needs to be 2 days in between with the first date range starting from the earliest date. I'm also trying to format the date to just YYYY-MM-DD without the time attatched.

gets earliest date:

```
SELECT min(Time_Stamp)
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

adds 2 days(but does not show range)

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,2,Time_Stamp)
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

exact desired result from the imgur link results above. Assuming it will need a "-" delimeter

```
1    2014-01-27 - 2014-01-29

2    2014-01-30 - 2014-02-01

3    2014-02-02 - 2014-02-04
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured out what you are saying

Comment: Why the downvote?! please explain! Did I not ask a question? Did I not give some direction? Did I not give my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

First off I wouldn't recommend formatting your output until you reach the presentation layer.  This is a bad habit to get into.  With that said, I think this query would do it:

```
SELECT id, 
       MIN(Time_Stamp) as start, 
       DATEADD(day, 2, MIN(Time_Stamp)) as end
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
GROUP BY Id
```

UPDATE:

If you just want to select the next two rows based on the original row, try this:

```
with start as
(
    SELECT id, 
           MIN(Time_Stamp) as startDate, 
           DATEADD(day, 2, MIN(Time_Stamp)) as endDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
    GROUP BY Id
),
results as
(

   SELECT startDate, endDate from start
   union
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, endDate), DATEADD(day, 3, endDate) FROM start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 4, endDate), DATEADD(day, 6, endDate) FROM start
)
SELECT * FROM results
```

While you can do the above in SQL, if you have the option to do this on your presentation layer I would recommend doing that.  This task is much better suited for something like C#.

Comment: Thanks Abe. This does give me the first range. But then how to create the 2nd and 3rd range? And the 1,2,3 in my question were to show row numbers so I took out the id in your query.

Comment: So what would the numbers be if it were 90 days in between? I dumbed it down to 2 just as an example

Comment: 1,91 for the first union and 92/182 for the second?  Feel free to play around with the numbers to get it to where ever you need.